# SQL: Why is calculating counts on two tables in one statement slow?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
select count(distinct ec.logicalid) from event_counts ec where ec.eventname = 'Searches'

select count(a.logicalid) from sf_accounts a
```

These two queries take only a few milliseconds each to run.

When I combine the queries into one, I get the same results but it takes two minutes to run:

```
select count(distinct ec.logicalid),  count(distinct a.logicalid) from event_counts ec, sf_accounts a where ec.eventname = 'Searches'
```

Am I missing something that would speed this query up?

Comment: without a `join` condition you are essentially doing a `cross join` of the tables involved.

Comment: Why are you not joining those tables on logicalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are cross-joining those tables, with old style joins at that. I am guessing you didn't know this was happening, [but you can read here on why you shouldn't use them](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

I suppose what you wanted was the results in one table. If so, use subqueries.

```
select (
    select count(distinct ec.logicalid) 
    from event_counts ec 
    where ec.eventname = 'Searches'
   ) as firstcount, 
       (
    select count(a.logicalid) 
    from sf_accounts a
   ) as secondcount
```

Otherwise, join your tables correctly

```
select 
   count(distinct ec.logicalid) 
   ,count(a.logicalid)
from event_counts ec
inner join sf_accounts a on a.logicalid = ec.logicalid
where ec.eventname = 'Searches'
```